# Android Image Processing Adjusting White Balance for Realism

Tags: android, image-processing

i am a beginner in Android programming.

Now i am doing a project that allows me to compare 2 photos in different lightings. The face detector will detect the face of the 2 photos and adjust one of them to be the same as the other.

I have done some researches, and found out maybe i could change the white balance of one of the image to match the color of the face to another. Is it possible?

Does anyone know any similar codes that i can look at or any methods/API that you can recommend me to use?

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: I would go on a different route, since automatic white balance will very likely not work reliable. I would try something related to histogram adaptation. I didn't bother searching for the most up-to-date work related to your specific needs, but http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/publications/dip/2002/ICPR2002/DATA/02_1_27.PDF provides the idea of what I'm suggesting.

Comment: thanks a lot but i got no idea how i can implement that but I will try to do more research on that.

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV will help you with this task
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html

Comment: I dummily clicked on the link expecting for some new research results on white balancing. So much disappointment, what kind of answer is that ? You might as well point him to the initial homepage of your preferred library.